# dokan edit functionality

Tags: plugins, themes, theme-customizer, wp-editor

how can we have a functionality that every vendor inputs whatsapp number, and when customer need they can chat on whatsapp with any product vendor, enquire them also can place order on whatsapp, Will it work on multivendor woocommerce site built on Dokan plugin

Comment: This is a very broad question for a programming Q&A site. Please [edit it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/380042/edit) and tell us what you've tried and what *specific* problem you're having.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. I assume you mean have a pop-up chat window for the whatsapp chats, but even if you could set up a whatsapp gateway - I don't think they exist - how would you handle chat sessions on whatsapp? What would happen if more than one customer tried to whatsapp a vendor at once, and how would that look at the whatsapp end?

Comment: Have you asked the DOKAN support team?